# How to set a default parameter for all edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, automata

### Question

How do you set all edges in an automaton to have the additional parameter double?

This should be easy, but I can't find the solution here or in the tikz/pgf manual or anywhere else.

`double` should not be overwritten by independent parameters: `edge[bend left]` with default `double` should thus be equivalent to `edge[bend left, double]`.

### Details

Currently, I'm using the parameter everywhere:

```
     \path[->] 
     (s0)+(-.5cm,.5cm) edge[bend right,double] (s0)
     (s0) edge[bend left,double] node[pos=0.3] {$a$} (s1)
     (s1) edge[bend left,double] node {$\epsilon,a$} (s0)
     (s0) edge[loop above,double] node {$\epsilon,a$} (s0)
     (s1) edge[loop below,double] node {$\epsilon,a$} (s1);
```

I tried `\path[->,double]` and various combinations of `\pgfset` and `\tikzstyle`, but I just don't know how to get to set `double` the edge's default parameter.

Comment: It needs `every edge/.append style`. But `double` will always come before unless you overwrite the default edge operation. See the manual Sec.16.12 (last part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add different style keys by appending or prefixing. In this context we need to append the `double` key to each `edge`. Since this appending is local to the path it doesn't affect succesive edges.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[->,every edge/.append style={double}] (0,0) edge[bend left] (1,1) (1,3)edge[loop above] ();
\path[->] (0,3) edge[bend left] (1,2) edge[loop above] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that `loop` only needs `()` you don't need to fill the brackets.

[image]